# Advanced grouping in domain name regex with Python3

Tags: regex, python-3.x, regex-group, domain-name

I have a program written in python3 that should **parse** several **domain names** every day and extrapolate data.
Parsed data should serve as input for a search function, for aggregation (statistics and charts) and to save some time to the analyst that uses the program.

Just so you know: I don't really have the time to study machine learning (which seems to be a pretty good solution here), so I chose to start with regex, that I already use.
I already searched the regex documentation inside and outside StackOverflow and worked on the debugger on regex101 and I still haven't found a way to do what I need.
**Edit (24/6/2019):** I mention machine learning because of the reason I need a complex parser, that is automate things as much as possible. It would be useful for making automatic choices like blacklisting, whitelisting, etc.

The parser should consider a few things:

- a maximum number of 126 subdomains plus the TLD
- each subdomain must not be longer than 64 characters
- each subdomain can contain only alphanumeric characters and the `-` character
- each subdomain must not begin or end with the `-` character
- the TLD must not be longer than 64 characters
- the TLD must not contain only digits

but I to go a little deeper:

- the first string can (optionally) contain a "usage type" like `cpanel.`, `mail.`, `webdisk.`, `autodiscover.` and so on... (or maybe a symple `www.`)
- the TLD can (optionally) contain a particle like `.co`, `.gov`, `.edu` and so on (`.co.uk` for example)
- the final part of the TLD is not really checked against any list of ccTLD/gTLDs right now and I don't think it will be in the future

What I thought useful to solve the problem is a regex group for the optional usage type, one for each subdomain and one for the TLD (the optional particle must be inside the TLD group)
With these rules in mind I came up with a solution:

```
^(?P<USAGE>autodiscover|correo|cpanel|ftp|mail|new|server|webdisk|webhost|webmail[\d]?|wiki|www[\d]?\.)?([a-z\d][a-z\d\-]{0,62}[a-z\d])?((\.[a-z\d][a-z\d\-]{0,62}[a-z\d]){0,124}?(?P<TLD>(\.co|\.com|\.edu|\.net|\.org|\.gov)?\.(?!\d+)[a-z\d]{1,64})$
```

The above solution doesn't return the expected results

---

I report here a couple of examples:

**A couple of strings to parse**

```
without.further.ado.lets.travel.the.forest.com  
www.without.further.ado.lets.travel.the.forest.gov.it
```

**The groups I expect to find**

- *FullMatch*`without.further.ado.lets.travel.the.forest.com`
  *group2*`without`
  *group3*`further`
  *group4*`ado`
  *group5*`lets`
  *group6*`travel`
  *group7*`the`
  *group8*`forest`
  *groupTLD*`.com`
- *FullMatch*`www.without.further.ado.lets.travel.the.forest.gov.it`
  *groupUSAGE*`www.`
  *group2*`without`
  *group3*`further`
  *group4*`ado`
  *group5*`lets`
  *group6*`travel`
  *group7*`the`
  *group8*`forest`
  *groupTLD*`.gov.it`

**The groups I find**

- *FullMatch*`without.further.ado.lets.travel.the.forest.com`
  *group2*`without`
  *group3*`.further.ado.lets.travel.the.forest`
  *group4*`.forest`
  *groupTLD*`.com`
- *FullMatch*`www.without.further.ado.lets.travel.the.forest.gov.it`
  *groupUSAGE*`www.`
  *group2*`without`
  *group3*`.further.ado.lets.travel.the.forest`
  *group4*`.forest`
  *groupTLD*`.gov.it`
  *group6*`.gov`

---

As you can see from the examples, a couple of particles are found twice and that is not the behavior i sought for, anyway. Any attempt to edit the formula results in unexpeted output.
Any idea about a way to find the expected results?

Comment: Regex doesn't seem appropriate here. Would `split(".")` not basically do the job? You can create sets of your whitelisted domains and extensions and check membership. Check `result[-1]` for membership in the domain set, and if it's not a match, use `result[-2:]` as your groupTLD.

Comment: and maybe regex the presence of a `.` before anything to avoid other checks?
or should I forget about regex at once?

Comment: I wouldn't completely rule out regex. This question is very legitimate, but I'd suggest a few improvements: 1) remove backstory (thank you, but it creates noise, obfuscating the requirements, which are not easy to grasp for me). 2) state the problem you're trying to solve clearly, detached from your [attempted solution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). 3) state your requirements, describing all edge cases. 4) post your examples and attempt and show how it isn't working (you're looking good here). This might help make the question a bit more approachable.

Comment: I rewrote the question... is it clearer like this?

Comment: Why the *heck* would machine learning, of all things, be a good solution here? It's about splitting strings, you don't even need regex for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it is possible to get the output exactly as you asked. I think that with a single pattern it cannot catch results in different groups(group2, group3,..).

I found one way to get almost the result you expect using [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) module.

```
match = regex.search(r'^(?:(?P<USAGE>autodiscover|correo|cpanel|ftp|mail|new|server|webdisk|webhost|webmail[\d]?|wiki|www[\d]?)\.)?(?:([a-z\d][a-z\d\-]{0,62}[a-z\d])\.){0,124}?(?P<TLD>(?:co|com|edu|net|org|gov)?\.(?!\d+)[a-z\d]{1,64})$', 'www.without.further.ado.lets.travel.the.forest.gov.it')
```

Output:

```
match.captures(0)
['www.without.further.ado.lets.travel.the.forest.gov.it']
match.captures[1] or match.captures('USAGE')
['www.']
match.captures(2)
['without', 'further', 'ado', 'lets', 'travel', 'the', 'forest']
match.captures(3) or match.captures('TLD')
['gov.it']
```

Here, to avoid taking `.` in groups I have added it in non-capturing group like this

```
(?:([a-z\d][a-z\d\-]{0,62}[a-z\d])\.)
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This a simple, well-defined task. There is no fuzzyness, no complexity, no guessing, just a series of easy tests to figure out everything on your checklist. I have no idea how "machine learning" would be appropriate, or helpful. Even regex is completely unnecessary.

I've not implemented everything you want to verify, but it's not hard to fill in the missing bits.

```
import string

double_tld = ['gov', 'edu', 'co', 'add_others_you_need']

# we'll use this instead of regex to check subdomain validity
valid_sd_characters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '-'
valid_trans = str.maketrans('', '', valid_sd_characters)

def is_invalid_sd(sd):
    return sd.translate(valid_trans) != ''

def check_hostname(hostname):
    subdomains = hostname.split('.')

    # each subdomain can contain only alphanumeric characters and
    # the - character
    invalid_parts = list(filter(is_invalid_sd, subdomains))
    # TODO react if there are any invalid parts

    # "the TLD can (optionally) contain a particle like
    # .co, .gov, .edu and so on (.co.uk for example)"
    if subdomains[-2] in double_tld:
        subdomains[-2] += '.' + subdomains[-1]
        subdomains = subdomains[:-1]

    # "a maximum number of 126 subdomains plus the TLD"
    # TODO check list length of subdomains

    # "each subdomain must not begin or end with the - character"
    # "the TLD must not be longer than 64 characters"
    # "the TLD must not contain only digits"
    # TODO write loop, check first and last characters, length, isnumeric

    # TODO return something
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't explain myself: machine learning would be useful for making automatic choices like blacklisting, whitelisting, etc. based on findings during time

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood. Although, when you already know what you allow and what you forbid, why would you not blacklist on that basis?

Comment: Because I don't know everything in advance. It can be that the resultset is too big for one person to check manually, so experience can come in handy and help trim that resultset.

Comment: But still you have set rules. It's either valid or it isn't on predetermined criteria. Nothing machine learning is made for. It does not matter how big the result set is, that's only relevant to how efficient the checking code is and how much computing power there is.